# Java servlet won't work with AWS Java SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, servlets

I've got a webpage written in JS with a couple of text fields and a few buttons. The page is Javascript, using JQuery, and I've got a Java Servlet as well. I've got the buttons hooked up to the servlet and everything works fine when deployed to Elastic Beanstalk through Eclipse... until I instantiate an AmazonS3 object in the servlet. Then, everything still works fine except for the button that calls the function that instantiates the S3 object. I click it and it just doesn't do anything, including running the code prior to the instantiation. When I comment the Amazon line out, it works fine.

What am I missing?

Here are my files:

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Program 4</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bttLoad').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'load'
                },
                url:'AjaxController',
                success: function(result){
                    $('#loadResult').html(result);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#bttClear').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'clear'
                },
                url:'AjaxController',
                success: function(result){
                    $('#clearResult').html(result);
                }
            });
        });

        $('#bttQuery').click(function(){
            var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
            var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    action: 'query'
                },
                url:'AjaxController',
                success: function(result){
                    $('#queryResult').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <fieldset>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Load Data" id ="bttLoad">
            <br>
            <span id="loadResult"></span>
        </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Clear Data" id ="bttClear">
            <br>
            <span id="clearResult"></span>
        </form>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <form>
            First Name <input type="text" id="firstName">
            Last Name <input type="text" id="lastName">
            <input type="button" value="Query" id ="bttQuery">
            <br>
            <span id="queryResult"></span>
        </form>
    </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>program4</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>AjaxController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AjaxController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.AjaxController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AjaxController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AjaxController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and finally, AjaxController.java (the servlet)

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AjaxController
 */
public class AjaxController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AjaxController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action.contentEquals("load")) {
            //String fullname = request.getParameter("fullname");
            out.println("load");
        }
        else if (action.contentEquals("clear")) {
            out.println("clear");
            myfunc(response);
            /*
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number1"));
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number2"));
            out.println(number1 + number2);
            myfunc(response);
            */
        }
        else if (action.contentEquals("query")) {
            //perform the query
            out.println("we gonna do da query, mon");
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
        }
        //doGet(request, response);
    }

    public static void myfunc(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            out.println(i);
        }
        AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Share stack-trace

Comment: @ErShakirAnsari So, I just spent the last 15 minutes trying to figure out how to see the stacktrace and I can't figure it out. I'm new to Eclipse. I set some breakpoints, open the stacktrace console, and debug on the server, but it just seems to run like normal, as though I just said "run this on elastic beanstalk."

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Turns out, the AWS SDK wasn't being uploaded to Elastic Beanstalk, even though I had added the jar to my project (I'm not using Maven).

What I had to do was...

First, drag and drop the jar into my project in Eclipse into the WebContent folder, WEB-INF, lib.

Second, right click the project and go to Build Path, Configure Build Path. In the window that opens, select the Libraries tab at the top. On the right, there are a few buttons. One of them is Add External JARs, and I had already previously done that to add the AWS SDK jar to my project. But I also had to click Add JARs. In the window that pops up, navigate to that lib folder mentioned previously and add the jar from here.

Once I did that and redeployed to Elastic Beanstalk, the button that called the function that contained the AWS code now works!